# How to avoid R AnomalyDetectionTs Error missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I am having a problem with AnomalyDetectionTs function of AnomalyDetection R package:

Following this post: https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series

```
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(AnomalyDetection)

ts_sample = data.frame(count(my_timestamp, 'timestamp'))

anomalies = AnomalyDetectionTs(ts_sample,
                               max_anoms=0.02,
                               direction='both',
                               only_last='day',
                               plot=TRUE,
                               title = 'Twitter CDMX')
```

Produces this out:

```
Error in if (data_sigma == 0) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am using the same data format, same data types, same data frame size and same parameters as in the official documentation:

```
> str(raw_data)
'data.frame':   14398 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ timestamp: POSIXlt, format: "1980-09-25 14:01:00" "1980-09-25 14:02:00" "1980-09-25 14:03:00" ...
 $ count    : num  182 176 184 178 165 ...
> str(ts_sample)
'data.frame':   14398 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ timestamp: POSIXlt, format: "2015-12-10 16:15:00" "2016-01-18 22:58:00" "2016-07-29 05:41:00" ...
 $ freq     : num  11 4 1 6 1 5 3 5 4 5 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `only_last='day'` is incorrect, `only_last` needs either be set to T(rue) or F(alse).

Comment: In my version only_last=FALSE using gives: Error in AnomalyDetectionTs(ts_sample, max_anoms = 0.02, direction = "both",  : 
  only_last must be either 'day' or 'hr'. So is not the solution.